# Symfony2 doctrine ManyToMany associations mapping invalid?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping, entity

I have two entities relating to this issue, and I want a join table to be able to cross reference values in each table.

Here is an explanation:

Entity ContainerType.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\Containers;

/**
 * ContainerType
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="container_type")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class ContainerType
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_added", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateAdded;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateModified;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Containers", inversedBy="type")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="container_type_containers")
     **/
    private $container;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->container = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

And entity Containers.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\ContainerType;

/**
 * Containers
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="containers")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Containers
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Containers", mappedBy="container")
     */
    private $type;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->type = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

And although the schema update works without problems, when I do a doctrine:schema:validate I get the following fail:

```
    [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\Containers' mapping is invalid:
* The association AppBundle\Entity\Containers#type refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\Containers#container which does not exist.
```

But the $container field DOES exist in ContainerType so I do not understand why it's trying to reference a field called container in the Containers entity?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thank you
Michael

Answer (score 1):

I think this code should works fine for you :)

ContainerType.php

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Containers", inversedBy="containersType")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="container_type_containers",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="container_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="container_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    protected $containers;
```

Containers.php

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ContainerType", mappedBy="containers")
     */
    protected $containersType;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized my error!

I had used the wrong target Entity in the Containers.php file, I should have used ContainerType as the target, instead I had Containers which is why it was trying to find the field in the wrong table!